# Stuck trying to get my c# text scroller to run smoothly

Tags: c#, text, scroll, marquee

I'm doing a small project where my vc# application needs to include a text scroller / news ticker. Application will be running on 30+ screens showing off internal ad production at my workplace. 
I've been googling and testing for a couple of months now but has yet to find / create a good solution where the movement is smooth and not choppy.

So my question is: is it possible to create perfect smooth scroll motion in c# or do I need to go about it some other way?

The code I'm using at the moment, part of a sample I edited, is running almost smooth except it seems to lag every 100 ms or so.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
namespace ScrollDemo1
{
public partial class NewsTicker : Panel
{
    private Timer mScroller;
    private int mOffset; 
    private string mText;
    private Size mPixels;
    private Bitmap mBuffer;
    public NewsTicker()
    {
        mScroller = new Timer();
        mScroller.Interval = 1;
        mScroller.Enabled = false;
        mScroller.Tick += DoScroll;
    }
    [Browsable(true)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return mText; }
        set
        {
            mText = value;
            mScroller.Enabled = mText.Length > 0;
            mPixels = TextRenderer.MeasureText(mText, this.Font);
            mOffset = this.Width;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void DoScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mOffset -= 1;
        if (mOffset < -mPixels.Width) mOffset = this.Width;
        Invalidate();
        Update();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mBuffer == null || mBuffer.Width != this.Width || mBuffer.Height != this.Height)
            mBuffer = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(mBuffer);
        Brush bbr = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor);
        Brush fbr = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
        Bitmap bmp = global::ScrollDemo1.Properties.Resources.text_bg1;
        TextureBrush tb = new TextureBrush(bmp);
        int iLoc = (this.Height / 2) - (mPixels.Height / 2);
        //Console.WriteLine(iLoc.ToString());
        //gr.FillRectangle(bbr, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
        gr.FillRectangle(tb, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
        gr.DrawString(mText, this.Font, fbr, mOffset, iLoc);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(mBuffer, 0, 0);
        bbr.Dispose();
        fbr.Dispose();
        gr.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you go with WPF. It has rich and easy to use support for animations and tends to be be very smooth since it is Direct3D based.

Comment: I was using WPF in the first place but had to move away as I ended up using to much cpu, some of the video ads are very high quality and I just couldn't get it to play with high fps.

Comment: That's a bit surpising. I have been playing back full HD videos very smoothly, hardware accellerated in WPF on average hardware (e.g. Core 2 Duo based laptop). You can also mix WPF with Windows Forms / ActiveX. Maybe use WPF for the overall chrome, including the scroller and use the embedded media player of you choice for the playback of the video?

Comment: Second problem I had with WPF was and still is: my app can run nice and smooth one time, next time I start it, it can run real slow. I have to be able to trust my app to run the same way every time its started. Just tested my old WPF newsticker (single customcontrol WPF app) and out of 10 runs it was smooth only once.

Comment: Startup times in WPF indeed soemtimes seem to be a bit slow, but once it is running, performance is usually superior to plain GDI+/WinForms rendering. You might be doing something subotimal, try a performance profiler to see what it is.

Comment: I've made a small wpf app test, that I think should move smooth. But it does only for about 20% of the time. Link: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=bf12b1393774eb89&resid=BF12B1393774EB89!301

Comment: I see now what you mean. It is really awful. It is the poor WPF textrendering performance that you have been a victim of. It has been complained about all over the internet. You can get around this by "prerendering" your text (e.g. by putting it into a VisualBrush or DrawingImage).

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could make an small example to get me going. My WPF experience is limited compared to winforms so I dont quite know where to start. I might be able to draw a image with the text (like I did in my winforms code) and use DoubleAnimation, but as it would end up very wide I think it would animate just as bad.

Comment: Wrap your text into Rectangle with a VisualBrush and animate that: `<Rectangle Height="60" Width="1680" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="2">
  <Rectangle.Fill>
  <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
     <VisualBrush.Visual>
   <TextBlock Height="60" Name="textBlock1" Width="1680" Text="Have a nice day!" FontSize="40" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FFF8FFFF" > 
     </VisualBrush.Visual>
  </VisualBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  <Rectangle.RenderTransform> 
   <TransformGroup> 
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="rtTTransform" />  
   </TransformGroup> 
  </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
 </Rectangle>`